# InvalidToken Error when using Rest API for Downloading file in an S3 AWS bucket in Android

Tags: android, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I am trying to use the Rest Api with temporary credentials to download images stored in an S3 bucket in AWS from my Android App. I need to use the rest API instead of the TransferUtility method included in the Android AWS SDK, because I want to use an image downloader for better performance. According to the official AWS docs, I need to add an Authorization header to the HTTP Get request, that is conform like this:

```
Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;
Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );
StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
Content-MD5 + "\n" +
Content-Type + "\n" +
Date + "\n" +
CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
CanonicalizedResource;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationConstructingCanonicalizedAmzHeaders

So, I obtain the Authorization header like this:

```
public String AuthorizationHeader (String dirToImageInBucket) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final AWSMobileClient mobileClient = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient();
    IdentityManager iM = mobileClient.getIdentityManager();
    AWSCredentialsProvider sCredProvider= iM.getCredentialsProvider();

    String secretKey = sCredProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey();
    String awsAccessKeyId = sCredProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId();

    Mac hmac = null;
    hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1"));

    Date dateT = new Date();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    String date = dateFormat.format(dateT);
    String token = "x-amz-security-token:" + Login_Related.geToken(activity) +"\nx-amz-date:" +date+"\n";
    String stringToSign = "GET" + "\n\n\n" + date + "\n" + token + "/" + dirToImageInBucket;
    String signature = ( Base64.encodeToString(hmac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT)).replaceAll("\n", "");
    return  "AWS" + " " + awsAccessKeyId + ":" + signature;
}
```

Then I add the "Authorization" header returned by the previous method to the HTTP GET request, and also I include the headers x-amz-date and x-amz-security-token in the request (with the values of date and temporary access token respectively). I am currently testing the request on Postman to test if I can download the image by adding the mentioned headers to GET request of the image URL, and every time I send it, I get the response :

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidToken</Code>
<Message>The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.</Message>
<Token-0>eyJraWQiOiJ4TFYxcVZiNG1IY3IrSWUxS....
```

I am sure I am using the right token, since the  others http requests in my app are working properly with that token. Can anyone please help me realize what am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks.

Edited to include the token method:

```
static public String geToken(Activity act) {
     AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(act.getApplicationContext());
      final AWSMobileClient mobileClient = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient();
      IdentityManager iM = mobileClient.getIdentityManager();
      IdentityProvider iP = iM.getCurrentIdentityProvider();
      token = iP.refreshToken();
      System.out.println("x-amz-security-token check this token: " + token);
      return token;
    }
```

Comment: Can you check if the token returned by Login_Related.geToken(activity) is valid or not?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's the token I am using all across the app. I will edit my answer to include it.

Comment: You are mixing the Cognito credentials (RefreshToken obtained from the Amazon Cognito Service) with the "x-amz-security-token". This header is meant for passing in the credentials received from STS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html). You can either use the S3 Low-level client and Cognito Identity (aws-sdk-android-s3) without using TransferUtility or send request to Rest Endpoint of S3 using STS credentials. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: Makes total sense. I will try your reply an let you know. Thanks